# Format of time in Excel

Tags: excel, format

I have a problem with time format. I have some data from report and in every row is time of some operation in strange format - when time is one minute and one second, in cell is 0:1:1. I need use average of times, but I can not, because it is bad format for Pivot table and `Qlik` etc... I tried formats as hh:mm:ss, only click on "time" on basic setting in Excel, but no change.

Have you any idea?

Comment: "Average of times"?? Can you explain that? Show us your current data, and expected output

Comment: I have table, where are 10 repair stations and these stations are doing operations in 30 seconds - 15 hours. I need average time of these stations. For example - one station has 2 operations - 1 minute and 5 minutes - average is 3 minutes. When I write 00:01:00 and 00:05:00 to blank sheet and click on average, then I have 00:03:00, but in my report, which is exported from other program is not possible.

Comment: Sounds like your times are text that looks like a time and not a number formatted like time.  Try converting the text to ta time with TIMEVALUE

Comment: Yes - it was my problem. TimeValue is solution. Can I use timevalue in existing table whitout adding a new column to table?

Comment: No not really... But you can create the new column then copy it and paste VALUES (not just paste) over the original values and then remove the new column. (all this can be made as an macro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve all of that with an array formula like this:

```
{=AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE(A1:A4))}
```

The above formula assumes that these times are in the cells `A1` through `A4`. The values in these cells will be converted to actual (usable) times and then the average of these times will be calculated.

Note, that the above formula is an array formula (visible by the curved braces around the formula). In order to enter an array formula you will have to press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` [as explained here in more detail](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

[image]